# How to avoid @RequestParam concatenating when a "+" operator is recieved as parameter?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring Framework and I'm trying to build this simple calculator app.
I've got this @RestController with this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/calculate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String calculate(@RequestParam(value = "a") String a, @RequestParam(value = "b") String b, @RequestParam(value = "operator") String operator) {
        //System.out.println(operator);
        if(operator.equals("+")){
            return String.valueOf((Integer.valueOf(a) + Integer.valueOf(b)));
        }
        if(operator.equals("-")){
            return String.valueOf((Integer.valueOf(a) - Integer.valueOf(b)));
        }
        if(operator.equals("*")){
            return String.valueOf((Integer.valueOf(a) * Integer.valueOf(b)));
        }
        if(operator.equals("/")){
            return String.valueOf((Integer.valueOf(a) / Integer.valueOf(b)));
        }
```

Ok, the problem here is that when I send a "+" parameter to sum the two variables the program is concatenating both int's instead of performing the sum.
The rest of the operations are working fine, except for the sum. I've tried sending a "/+" without luck.
Any idea how this can be solved and most importantly, why is this happening ?
Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware of that `+` is a special character. To use `+` as a value you need to encode it as `%2B` in your GET request.

For example:

http://localhost:8080/calculate?a=3&b=5&operator=%2B

Comment: if(operator.equals("+")){
            return String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(a) + Integer.parseInt(b)));
        }
Still not workiing :(

Comment: When i checked in https://www.compilejava.net/  it worked as expected. You can also check with this code:                             String operator = "+";
String a = "5";
String b = "3";
String result = null;
if(operator.equals("+")){ 
result = String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(a) + Integer.parseInt(b)));
}
System.out.println(result);

Comment: that's the thing, i believe Spring is doing something odd behind the scenes, because it should work alright, but it isn't.

Comment: @NachoZveDeLaTorre did you try it? Solved the problem?

Comment: Yes, I've tried, but it didn't solved the problem :( ... no worries, I've solved it in a different way, putting "plus" intead of "+" .... it's not what i wanted but ....